# Vba excel- need to get file name in separate column in master sheet. Copying data from multiple excel to master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In this code I am copying data from multiple excel but need those excel file name in master excel in z column. Here I am able to copy the data's but getting error in getting file name. Anyone help me for the same. Have attached the code.

```
Sub PC()

    Dim MyFile As String, MyFiles As String, FilePath As String
    Dim t as range
    Dim erow As Long
    '~~>; Put additional variable declaration
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
   
    Set extwbk = ThisWorkbook
     Set x = extwbk.worksheets("Data").Range("M2:M1048576")


    FilePath = InputBox("Enter File Path")
    MyFiles = InputBox("Ente File extension with File path")
    
    MyFile = Dir(MyFiles)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your declared variables
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook 'if you want to consolidate files in this workbook
    Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets("Data") 'replace Sheet1 to suit

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        'Debug.Print MyFile
        If MyFile <> "Aug-2017.xlsm" Then
            
            Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath & MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1) 'I used index, you said there is only 1 sheet
            '~~> Now directly work on your object
            With wsMaster
                erow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row
             
                wsTemp.Range("N4:X104823").Copy
                
                .Range("A" & erow).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                x.Offset.value = Activesheet.Name
               
                
           
.Range("M" & erow).offset(0,12).pasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With
            
            Set wsTemp = Nothing
            Set wbTemp = Nothing
        End If
        '~~> Load the new file
        MyFile = Dir
        
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Have shared the code

Comment: Yeah you're gonna have to edit that again so it's not one line

Comment: Have copied the code in proper manner

Comment: Anyone help me for this code

Comment: *Here I am able to copy the data's but getting error in getting file name*  What does this actually mean? What error? Which line raises the error?

Comment: t.offset(0,13).value=Worksheet.name

Comment: Coming error in this line. This code will merge the excel sheet which we given path but unable to get the those respective file name on separate column.

Comment: What is `t`? I see no declaration of it.

Comment: @JohnyL Hello John, I need excel name on column 13

Comment: I'm asking once again: what is `t` variable? The line with this variable gives you error, but I don't see any declaration of it.

Comment: @JohnyL have mentioned t as variant but again getting error.

Comment: And where it is declared? Where and how it is assigned?

Comment: @JohnyL have edited the code. Dim t as Range

Comment: Finally! Now show me where do you assign something to `t`.

Comment: @JohnyL I am new to vba code. Exactly not getting the file name the sheet we taking the data's can you help me for the same.

Comment: OK... We found out that `t` is `Range`. Then I ask you to show me where do you assign something to it? There must be a string beginning with `Set t = ...`.

Comment: By the way, you didn't answer to and marked as answer two of your previous questions.

Comment: @JohnyL here my code is I am copying data from one workbook to master workbook. While copying I need file name in mater workbook. For that only I tried within a loop for getting filename

Comment: Beg your pardon, but do you understand what I'm asking from you? Perhaps, you have some troubles with translation?

Comment: @JohnyL sorry clearly I don't understand your questions

Comment: Then I can't help you.

Comment: @JohnyL Thanks for your patience to try to answer my queries.

Comment: Please, re-read carefully my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990602/vba-excel-need-to-get-file-name-in-separate-column-in-master-sheet-copying-dat?noredirect=1#comment91019038_51990602)

Comment: @JohnyL let's try to add the string

Comment: `t` does not represent anything until and unless you assign it. You haven't assigned it, so it's `Nothing` (which you can verify in the Locals window of VBE). So you'll get an Object Variable or With Block not Set error. You need to assign `t` some range, for example `Set t = Range("A1")`, etc. Which range you assign is a decision you need to make.

Comment: @DavidZemens Ok. Will try to assign the value

Comment: @DavidZemens Have assigned that variable but still getting error

Comment: Currently getting first file name in entire M column the range which given in set rang code. But required all the sheet name which copying data as per loop.